# How to configure server to make php mail() function to work

Tags: php, function, email

I moded my personal blog on a VPS. I already configured all: apache with `mod_rewrite`, php, curl, pear, mysql and ftp. But I noticed that the *php `mail()`* function doesn't work. I searched on the net but I didn't find an answer to my issue. Since i'm still a newbie to this type of stuff I want to ask to the community if someone can explain me how to achieve that.

Thank you very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660774/configure-mail-server-to-work-with-php?rq=1?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to use the mail package of pearl but I want to configure the native method mail() of PHP

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Linux Server

Comment: You probably need a mail server and a working sendmail command pointing to it.

Comment: Ok, run a script with this function: _phpinfo()_. What's the output from the line _sendmail_path_?

Comment: sorry for delay, _sendmail_path_ is _/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i_ but it doesen't work

Comment: Check if _sendmail_ is working on your ubuntu server.